# In $n>5$, topology = algebra

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, surgery-theory

During the study of the [surgery theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surgery_theory) I faced following sentence:

> Surgery theory works best for $n > 5$, when
>   "**topology = algebra**".

I don't know what is the meaning of topology=algebra. Can someone clear the sentence to me?

Comment: There is a completely algebraic theory of surgery developed by Ranicki. See the following notes (especially section 5): http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/ranicki.pdf

Comment: This is quite beautifully explained in the first chapter of Scorpan's nice *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds*. I recommend it strongly.

Comment: The meaning is simply that the $h$- and $s$-cobordism theorems only  hold in dimensions $n\geq 5$, where they make algebraic machinery effective. For an explanation of what happens below dimension $5$ (particularly dimension $4$), I can't recommend Scorpan's book highly enough.

Answer (score 5):

In the interest of recording the answers in the comments above and removing the question from the "unanswered" queue, I note the following.

Henry Horton:

> There is a completely algebraic theory of surgery developed by Ranicki. See the following notes (especially section 5): http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/ranicki.pdf

PseudoNeo:

> This is quite beautifully explained in the first chapter of Scorpan's nice *The Wild World of 4-Manifolds*. I recommend it strongly.